# uinput won't load - even manually

Tags: 11.10, remote-control

I'm trying to get input to work so that I can remote control Myth with a Sony PS3 remote control.  The remote pairs okay - but none of the buttons on it work.

I've added uinput to /etc/modules - but that hasn't made any difference.  I've also tried launching uinput manually by entering 'sudo modprobe uinput'.  No errors are reported when I do that - but when I then enter 'lsmod | grep uinput', nothing gets returned.

I'm perplexed.  Various forums suggest that uinput is broken on Ubuntu - but surely that isn't the case, is it?  I'm running 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, part of the the reason is that uinput is compiled into the kernel - so of course lsmod won't show anything!  On the other hand though, this still doesn't explain why key presses from the remote control aren't being detected.  If I learn anything new I'll be sure to pass it on.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get install blueman` and connect the device with 'Bluetooth Manager'.
This not loaded the uinput module, but your Sony PS3 remote control could work.